# Generic selenium testing images

Tags: selenium

With selenium can one run a test which check all images on a current page if they contain ALT attribute and report images not having it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The first thing you need to do is decide which selenium you want to use.

- You can use [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_selenium_ide.html), where a test consists of an HTML table.
- You can use [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html), where  you write  a test in a programming language (eg. C#, Java, PHP, Ruby, etc).

The latter is a little more complex at first, but if you want real power, you will use that method.

Then, you'll need to learn how to find all the images on a page.
`//img` is a good XPath query to use. For Xpath details, see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp), and especially [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

Then you'll want to find images with an alt attribute: `//img[@alt]`

One approach would be to count how many images there are, and subtract the number with alt attributes.

Comment: After some reading I found out that you can locate all images that don't have an ALT attribute with using the xpath expression //img[not(@alt)]

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this in WebDriver (soon to be Selenium 2). The following example is for TestNG/Java but other client languages are available.

```
List<WebElement> images = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[not(@alt)]"));
assertEquals(images.size(), 0);
```

For more feedback you could also use something like the following to output details of the images without alt attributes:

```
for(WebElement image : images) {
    System.out.println(image.getAttribute("src"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar test but we grab the page's Html and parse out the images with a regular expression and then match on a second regular expression looking for the alt tag. I haven't done a speed test, but I think it might be faster than doing the Xpath route.